# Importing external py script runs just on declaration

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have 2 .py scripts in my Raspberry Pi 3. Script1.py is just a button script and Script2.py is the main script. I want to run the Script2 only on button press in Script1.

Now I know this Q has been asked before. And I have read their solutions but none of them working for me.

I essentially want to run the Script2 as a module. So that the whole script also runs and I can also get the variables from that script. This is what I am doing

Script1.py

```
Import  Script2
Import Rpi.GPIO

if_button_is_pressed:
os.system("Script2.py")
```

Yes, I have tried execfile also. Doesn't work. The issue is, when I run Script1, the Script2 also automatically runs, without waiting for the button press. Seems like the Import function  imports the scripts and runs it too.

My next move was this

```
Import Rpi.GPIO

if_button_is_Pressed:
import Script2
```

This runs fine, but ONLY on 1st execution. If I insert a while(True) loop, after the Script2 has been imported and run, it does not run the next time.

```
Import Rpi.GPIO

while(True)
if_button_is_pressed:
import Script2
```

When I press the button, the Script2 runs fine. Then when I press the button again, It does not run the Script2. Just skips it and goes onto next command.

What may be the issue? Thank You in advance

Comment: Please fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
Import Rpi.GPIO
Import cv2

while(button_is_pressed):
    import Script2
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You should catch the action while the button is pressed and check using this value.

**`cv2.waitKey()`** is a keyboard binding function. Its argument is the time in milliseconds. The function waits for specified milliseconds for any keyboard event. If you press any key in that time, the program continues. If 0 is passed, it waits indefinitely for a key stroke. It can also be set to detect specific key strokes like, if key a is pressed etc which we will discuss below. Taken from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html).

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. Same output. Imports the Script2 and runs it well for the first time. After than Script2 does not run.

Comment: @ShantanuJagtap Try to import 'cv2' module and use `cv2.waitKey(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the portion of script 2 that would normally run on import into a function that accepts no arguments. This is probably the entire script. Let's call the function `run`.

In script 1, import script 2 as usual. Now nothing will run during the import. Respond to button clicks with `script2.run()`.

If you still need to be able to run script 2 as a script, add the following lines at the end of it (outside of the `run` function):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   run()
```